# Saving data in div after page refresh

Tags: html, jquery

I am creating a search bar where the user can select parameters which creates a chip in the search bar. This chip will be created dynamically for every selection in a div with the class name 'chips'. After submitting the selection, the page redirects based on the selection. As the chips were dynamically created, they will be deleted on page reload. My question: Is there a way to store this dynamic data without deleting it after the page refresh?

```
  <div class="chips" id="createdChips" >
         <span> class ='someclass' </span>
         <span> class ='someclass' </span>          
  </div>
```

Comment: What about cookies and local storage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Comment: Why is this question tagged C#? There is no mention of the language in the question.

Comment: @Danilo  using cookies can be a problem, if user wants to clear them. I tried with local storage but it is not working

Comment: @Heretic Monkey The question you taggged gave me some info. Thanks for that and sorry for the wrong tag c#, it was a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You can store your dynamically created data in cookies or session storage. When your page load, search if there's data stored in above storage and draw the chips based on data.

Answer (score 2):

delete on browser close:

```
// Store item
sessionStorage.setItem('example', 'some item');

// Get Item
sessionStorage.getItem('example') // 'some item'

// Remove Item
sessionStorage.remove('example');

// Remove all items
sessionStorage.clear();
```

never be deleted unless the user clears website data (through browser settings):

```
// Store item
localStorage.setItem('example', 'some item');

// Get Item
localStorage.getItem('example') // 'some item'

// Remove Item
localStorage.remove('example');
```